# Does anybody know where I can get nba first half info from prizepicks?

Tags: json, parsing, url

There's an api (https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=7&per_page=10000000&single_stat=true)

which contains all the information about NBA props and the lines set for them. Does anybody know the URL similar to this but for the NBA 1st half or second half? Been trying to find this but no luck. I know this is a longshot but I thought I'd ask

Tried different league_id in the URL's but these pertain to different sports

Answer (score 0):

The league id for NBA1H is 84, so the url would be: https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=84

I also found the NBA1Q id, which is 192.

I'm unsure what the NBA2H or NBA4Q league ids are because they aren't actively posted in PrizePicks and I was unable to track them down. You can search for their ids by using the find command (Command F) in https://api.prizepicks.com/projections.